# Android ArrayList remove just plain doesn't work

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to delete an element from an ArrayList and nothing happens.

This is for an Android development course - have to remove an element from an ArrayList by index. I've put logs before and after the removal and nothing happens.

```java
    // at the top of MainActivity.java

    ArrayList<String> notes;
    Integer bigPos;

    // in a dialog box positive button onClick method
    notes.remove(new Integer(bigPos)); // just to force it to execute the integer method
    // bigPos is set to pos in the long click listener before the alert.show is executed. I know from logs that the bigPos and notes are in scope. the code RUNS it just doesn't DO anything... notes is the same after the removal.
```

I expect the output to be the notes ArrayList with element # bigPos to be gone. No change occurs.

Comment: why are you trying to remove interger from a string list?

Comment: Also aren't reference types removed by memory adrress not value? How you gonna remove something that's not in the list ?

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Use `int`, not `Integer`, for `bigPos`

Step #2: Remove `new Integer()` from your `remove()` call

As it stands, right now, I think that you are attempting to remove a `String` whose value is the string representation of `bigPos`. `remove()` has two variants:

- `remove(int)` removes by index
- `remove(Object)` removes by value

If for some reason you really really really want to use `Integer` for `bigPos`, then replace `remove(new Integer(bigPos))` with `remove(bigPos.intValue())`.

Comment: Worked first time! Thanks bro! My problem was I thought an integer was an integer was an integer. Apparently not... :-)

Comment: @cdnbcguy: `Integer` is the "boxed" object type, whereas `int` is a primitive. Many times, they are interchangeable. This time, they weren't.